# Back button not made on navigation bar

Tags: ios, uinavigationitem

I started out with a navigation based project and am pushing further views onto the controller. The problem is that if I do not give a title to the navigation item then the back button is not drawn! Only if I give the navigation bar a title, will the back button come. It seems apple could'nt write "back" or "go back" in case of **NO** title. I do not want to give the navigation item a title(I'll use a label inside my view). So how do I fix this?

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
[super viewDidLoad];
self.navigationItem.title = @"Home"; /// <- without setting the title, the back button won't show !
}
```

In the view didLoad method, if I remove the title, the back button won't show

Comment: Can we see some code? Pretty please? Also, feel free to choose a username and stay awhile.

Comment: sure...I've added some code. Don't think will be pretty useful though. Visit my repo (github.com/aakash272/pagingScroll) and try it out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just create the back button yourself:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    UIBarButtonItem *back = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Back"
                                                             style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain
                                                            target:nil
                                                            action:nil];
    [[self navigationItem] setBackBarButtonItem:back];
    [back release];
}
```

(If you prefer dot notation, `self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem = back;`)

Comment: I am new to objective-c,what i saw many times and i don;t understand is that why you immediately call release on back button after you create ? As far as i understood release decreases the reference count by 1....

Comment: It does decrease the reference count. This method created it (which sets the reference count to 1). So when the method is done with it, it releases it, for a net zero increase. Otherwise, you're creating a memory leak. …Now the line above may do something with the reference count, but it doesn't know that. What anything else does with the reference count is not this method's concern.