# xcode iphone back button

Tags: xcode, button, view, back

Seems like this would be a simple thing, but I cannot find any good info on it.

I just want to be able to 'force' the back button to show.  I have a main view and when I transfer to another view there is no back button.  But then if I transfer to a 3rd view, the back button appears.  This seems to always be the case.  Only the 2nd transferred to view shows a back button.  I need it to show up on all views except the main view.

I dont need to override it, just simply force it to show where it is not showing...

Comment: This might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6921639/back-button-not-made-on-navigation-bar

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old question, but this might help...

...sometimes you need to embed a view inside a Navigation Controller for the back button to show. Simply select your view controller and select Editor -> Embed In -> Navigation Controller.

If the button does not show (usually if you are presenting a modal view rather than push) then you will need to manually make a 'Cancel' button. Create an action for this and in the method put (I call my method switchback):

```
￼-(IBAction)switchback:(id)sender {
    [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

Comment: Did this answer help you to find your solution to your question, if so, please accept this answer. Check this [link](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) out for how to mark answers. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Patch's solution (dismissModalViewController)had been unfortunately deprecated and replaced by dismissViewControllerAnimated.
Here is the current one:

```
-(IBAction)switchback:(id)sender {
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}
```