# Add UIBarButtonItem to UINavigationController on iphone sdk

Tags: iphone, ios

I want to add back button on UINavigationController,I am trying Below Code :

```
EGOPhotoViewController *photoController = [[EGOPhotoViewController alloc] initWithPhotoSource:source];
    UINavigationController *navController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:photoController];
    navController.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleCrossDissolve;
    navController.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationFullScreen;
   // UINavigationBar *my_bar;
    //UINavigationItem *my_item=[[UINavigationItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"test"];
    UIBarButtonItem* button = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle: @"Back"
                                                               style: UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered
                                                              target: navController
                                                              action: @selector(onBack)];
    //my_item.rightBarButtonItem = button;
    [[navController navigationItem] setRightBarButtonItem:button];
    self.title=@"Gallery";
    [self presentModalViewController:navController animated:YES];
```

this code output is Below:

[image]

code does not add Back Button in UINavigationController.I am adding Code to Back button on UINavigationController,what's Wrong on my code...!

Please any one help me...!

Thanks..!

Comment: Take a look at this:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6921639/back-button-not-made-on-navigation-bar

Answer (score 3):

Try to add the UIBarButtonItem from the rootviewcontroller class (photoController) viewDidLoad method.

```
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem =  [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle: @"Back"
                                                           style: UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered
                                                          target: navController
                                                          action: @selector(onBack)];
```

Comment: Did you mean `self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem=...`?

Comment: I guess that he wanted to add a button to the right side ([[navController navigationItem] setRightBarButtonItem:button];) :)

Comment: Back button feels better on the left because the pushed views are animated from the right and the popped ones are animated from the left. So you **should** make it on the left!